# Android testCompile project not working

Tags: android, gradle, robolectric

I am using Robolectric and the "android-unit-test" plugin in my android project. I have multiple modules (eg `foo` and `bar`) and would like to use the same test runner across all the modules. To achieve this I created a `Test` module to hold my test runner and any custom shadow classes. In foo's build.gradle I have `testCompile project (":main:Test")`however android studio will not import my runner unless I also include `androidTestCompile (":main:test")`. Furthermore, when I run `./gradlew test` from the command line I get various errors saying that my test runner and shadow classes cannot be found. Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your given information I guess you missed one little aspect: test classes appear not in jars.

When your shared TestRunner is under `src/test/java` then other modules will not see it. When I'm correct then place you TestRunner at `src/main/java` and all modules should have access to our support classes.

Here is also an example where i did the same https://github.com/nenick/AndroidAppDevelopment

Comment: Awesome thanks for the example, I actually had a couple other issues. The first was that my Test module was an android library. Changing it to java and using the `@Implements(className = "android.")` for my shadows fixed my issues thanks!

Comment: Since Android Studio has unit test support you may avoid extra plugins to use robolectric. Here is an example https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric